# Can not insert images inline OpenWYSIWYG with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, openwysiwyg

My previous question was here
[missing images OpenWYSIWYG editor , Code igniter Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867050/missing-images-openwysiwyg-editor-code-igniter-structure/16869470?noredirect=1#16869470).

I was able to load icon images and can upload image, but I can't insert image into inline text:

[image]

Please see the images for a clearer picture. It just won't add them to the textarea.

Modified 1-6-2013

After fixing

```
assets/js/openwysiwyg/addons/imagelibrary/insert_image.php.
```

I was able to add image frame

how ever URL enter is wrong

[image]

URL should be

`app_name/assets/js/openwysiwyg/uploads`

How can I fixed that?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it , by the solution from this link

http://www.ussamerica.org/Scripts/openwysiwyg_v1.4.7/docs/addons.html

after changing

`/assets/js/openwysiwyg/addons/imagelibrary/config.inc.php`

like this it works now

```
$imagebaseurl = '/app_name/assets/js/openwysiwyg/uploads/';
```

I am posting this as it might helpful to someone in the future.